# perfstat_process not declared in libperfstat.h on AIX 6.1

Tags: c, performance, monitoring, aix

I am trying to write a program that computes the CPU process utilization on AIX 6.1, which need to take into account of the virtualized processor environment.  More information are from the link below:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/perfstat_cpu.htm

My program uses a datastructure called "perfstat_process_t", which is documented in the AIX 6.1 reference page:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.files%2Fdoc%2Faixfiles%2Flibperfstat.h.htm

But on my local system's /usr/include/libperfstat.h, it does not have that data structure declaration and other functions specifically related to process information gathering.  In the libperfstat header file, I can only find the functions/datastructure used for computing overall CPU usage, such as perfstat_cpu(), but not on the process level such as perfstat_process().

I suspect that this might be due to availability between different AIX versions, but from researching online, the functions related to perfstat_process_t should be available since AIX 5.3.

Just wondering if anyone have seen similar discrepncies before?  My AIX version 6.1 is the following:

bash-3.2$ oslevel -s
6100-02-08-1015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a system with apar IZ94926:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IZ94926

or one of its sister apars.  I can find it only in 6.1 and 7.1.  I can't find it anywhere in 5.3.

HTH